# Select2 multiple values and if/then

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-select2

I am trying to have a div show if 2 options in a select2 box are chosen using jquery but am unsuccessful.

For example - my 2 choices are First and Second:

```
<select id="choose1" multiple="multiple">
<option value="first">First</option>
<option value="second">Second</option>
</select>
```

I have 2 divs that hidden:

```
<div id="first">
ABC
</div>
<div id="second">
XYZ
</div>

$('#first').hide();
$('#second').hide();
```

And now my jquery to show the divs:

```
$('#choose1').select2();

$('#choose1').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var x = 'first';
    var y = 'second'
    var z = ['first','second'];

    if (val == x) {
        $('#first').show();
    }

  else if (val == y) {
    $('#second').show();
  }

  else if (val == z) {
  $('#first').show();
  $('#second').show();
  }

    });
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your `divs`

```
<div class="option-div" id="first">ABC</div>
<div class="option-div" id="second">XYZ</div>
```

And modify your js to use this in your change listener:

```
$('#choose1').change(function () {
    $(".option-div").hide();
    $.each($(this).val(), function(i, v){
      $("#" + v).show();
    });
});
```

Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/Leankppt/

Answer (score 0):

There might be issue with loading of jQuery, you have to place jQuery before `select2`

See your code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/L4tkx7rc/